# Confusion to read html table contents using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

here is the `HTML` content:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="data">
<tr class="colhead">
            <th colspan="3">Expression</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="colhead">
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>List</th>
</tr>           
<tr class="rowLight">
    <td width="40%">
            Task1
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
             Assigned to 
        </td>
        <td width="40%">
             Harry
    </td>

</tr>           
<tr class="rowDark">
     <td width="40%">
                    Task2
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                     Rejected by 
                </td>
                <td width="40%">
                    Lopa 
                </td>
</tr>

<tr class="rowLight">
    <td width="40%">
            Task5
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
             Accepted By 
        </td>
        <td width="40%">
            Mathew
        </td>
</tr>
```

Now I have to get the values as below : (the below table is nothing but an Excel table,that i will build up,once reached to the values.)

```
Task    Action        List
Task1   Assigned to   Harry
Task2   Rejected by   Lopa
Task5   Accepted By   Mathew
```

A lay man solution what I know as below:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   soup = BeautifulSoup(source_URL)

alltables = soup.findAll( "table", {"border":"2", "width":"100%"} )

t = [x for x in soup.findAll('td')]

[x.renderContents().strip('\n') for x in t]
```

But in my above `HTML` content such structure not present,so how to approach? Please guide me here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.stripped_strings` to get the 'interesting' text from a table row:

```
rows = table.find_all('tr', class_=('rowLight', 'rowDark'))
for row in rows:
    print list(row.stripped_strings)
```

This outputs:

```
[u'Task1', u'Assigned to', u'Harry']
[u'Task2', u'Rejected by', u'Lopa']
[u'Task5', u'Accepted By', u'Mathew']
```

or, to pull everything into one list of lists (with, by request, the last row not included):

```
data = [list(r.stripped_strings) for r in rows[:-1]]
```

which becomes:

```
data = [[u'Task1', u'Assigned to', u'Harry'], [u'Task2', u'Rejected by', u'Lopa']]
```

The result of `.find_all()`, a `ResultSet`, acts just like a Python list and you can slice it at will to ignore certain rows, for example.

Comment: Woowwwwwww............ you are like a `Pyhton-bs-4` god of mine! Okie here one thing i forgot to mentioned,which is that - (a) `I am not interested to roll over to last row of the table,only `last row - 2`. So how to do so? (b) If I want to get the values of each list,which way to do so?

Comment: Is it possible what I said above? @Martijin

Comment: The `rows` list is just like other lists; you can slice it: `rows[:-1]`. To turn this all into a list of lists, do `data = [list(r.stripped_strings) for r in rows[:-1]]`.

Comment: Can you edit your `code`, I am new to this platform. So its taking time to understand what is it all and how?

Comment: You catched me perfectly,but one thing you missed I think! that is when we are looping through the `rows` then how would I restricts the number of iterations,say If I don't need to go to the last two rows always!