# Conflicts in the concept of .next_element and .previous_element BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I just went thorugh the B4 docs and got some concept about the `Going back and forth` in the `html family tree`.

```
last_a_tag = soup.find("a", id="link3")
last_a_tag
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
last_a_tag.next_element
# u'Tillie'  
last_a_tag.previous_element
# u' and\n' ## upto this is Good to understand!
last_a_tag.previous_element.next_element
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

Confliction comes into my mind here. according to `.Previous_element` concept `last_a_tag.previous_element.next_elementt` should give `<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">` but then why the full one as shown above?

**Edit**

```
last_a_tag.previous_element
# u' and\n'  <~~Perfect
last_a_tag.previous_element.next_element
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

Why not till the below?

```
#<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">
```

How till below part?
    `Tillie</a>`  <~~ here is the confusion

help me to understand.

Comment: ...so you expect `tag.next_element.previous_element != tag != tag.previous_element.next_element`?!

Comment: @katrielalex It seems you didn't get my confusion! Can you re read the description. I am not opposing anything,trying to understand the logic. If it is clear to you please help me to get into your level!

Comment: <a>...</a> is an element and if that is your confusion, then it has nothing to do with the back and forth bit

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: Indeed, I don't get your confusion. I don't get at all what you are asking then.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you _do not expect_ `.next_element.previous_element` to do nothing. Why do you think that?

Comment: @deinonychusaur Let me clear myself how `Going back and forth` works. It takes elements as they parsed as per documentation. right? So If I take this `<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>` then `<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">` parsed firts, then `Tillie` and next `</a>` . So why the `<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">` didn't come by the `last_a_tag.previous_element.next_elementt`

Comment: @MartijnPieters please see my comments I just write above! And I am not telling I am wright. I am trying to clear myself with the knowledge!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: I thought I got it, but then I know I didn't. Perhaps you are confusing `last_a_tag.next_element` with `last_a_tag.previous_element.next_element`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah! Thanks God, you get my pain, where i am getting confused. Also would like to know how the `back and forth` concept works? if you have any clear example handy with you!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: Nope, still don't get why you are confused. You ask for the next element of the previous element, so you arrive right back where you started from. But that appears to confuse you!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: And BS elements keep a reference to their document, so they 'know' where in the tree they belong, making it possible for the `.next_*` and `.previous_*` pointers, as well as other methods such as `.parent()` to return other elements in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still looking at a reference to the tag, and when that's printed, all it's contained children are printed too.

A tag is not just the opening `<a ...>` element, it also includes any children and the closing element. You still need to reach those children in the tree, via `.next_element` (which would be `u'Tillie'`), for example.

Navigating around the tree does not move between opening and closing pieces of text, it moves among the elements in a tree. The original XML/HTML document defined those elements in a certain ordering, but that's not what you are looking at here. You are looking at the nested structure of tags and text fitting inside other tags, all the way to the root.

So the following HTML structure:

```
<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
```

becomes a structure along the following lines:

```
p
\
  a
  \
    "Elsie"
  ", "
  a
  \
    "Lacie"
  " and "
  a
  \
    "Tillie"
  "; and they lived at the bottom of a well."
```

(simplified to remove a lot of whitespace).

If you have a reference to the last `a` element, the previous element in that set is the text `" and "`, the next is `"Tillie"`. After `"Tillie"` comes the text `"; and they lived at the bottom of a well."`. Before the text `" and "` comes the text `"Lacie"`, etc.

Comment: Okay! It seems I am catching the point! Now just tell me how `last_a_tag.next_element` gives only `# u'Tillie'  `

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: Text blocks are elements too. You have there a [`NavigableString` instance](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), not a regular python unicode object. They have `.next_*` and `.previous_*` references too.

Comment: I am not able to connect the way it works in both directions and only one way i can understand.[.next_element and .previous_element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) defination is understandble for me only to the `.next_element` method but not the `.previous_element`.

Comment: Why is that understandable only in one direction? `next_element` means 'first child', unless there are no children, then 'next sibling' unless there are no siblings, then recurse up the parents until there is a next sibling again. `previous_element` means inner-previous sibling (or rather, it's last child, recursively), until there are no siblings, in which case it goes to the parent. If you start at the `root` element, using `.next_sibling` you can visit *every* element in the tree, then go all the way back again using `.previous_element`, which would go in reverse order.

Comment: Okay! you logic sounds good now,but in the documentation they mentioned something like order of parsing - which made me confused!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU: That ordering happens to match the way you find the elements in the document. Opening tag -> start an element, adding it to the parent, this is the new parent for every thing that follows. Closing tag -> done with this element, close it, make it's parent the new parent we add the next element we parse to.

Comment: I understand now your point. If possible can you edit your answer to show the Parse tree and their traversal with this Example?

Comment: If it possible for me I would really give you +100 vote.Really appreciated you felt my pain to understand the concept and accordingly help me out. I am very much happy!! :)

Comment: Can you help me here? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156546/confusion-to-read-html-table-contents-using-beautifulsoup